# Mysql delete duplicate records except one has max time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has multiple RFID records and each record has a column called time and what I want is deleting duplicate RFID recods except one which has max time.

table name is attendance_images(id,RFID,time,year,month,day) and my query is as below:

```
DELETE t FROM attendance_images AS t LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT max( t1.time ) AS time
   FROM attendance_images AS t1
   WHERE t1.year=2016
   AND t1.month=8
   AND t1.day=4
   AND t1.time < 120000
   GROUP BY t1.RFID
) keep ON t.time = keep.time
WHERE keep.time IS NULL
AND t.year =2016
AND t.month =8
AND t.day =4
AND t.time < 120000
```

The query effect is (`0 rows deleted. (Query took 0.0034 sec)`) but the table has duplicate records according condition.

[image]

Please help to fix this issue.

Comment: Please share the `show create table <table_name>` code along with some data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to match on `RFID` as well:

```
DELETE t
    FROM attendance_images AS t LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT RFID, max( t1.time ) AS time
          FROM attendance_images AS t1
          WHERE t1.year = 2016 AND t1.month = 8 AND t1.day = 4 AND t1.time < 120000
          GROUP BY t1.RFID
         ) keep
         ON t.time = keep.time AND t.RFID = keep.RFID
WHERE keep.time IS NULL AND
      t.year = 2016 AND t.month = 8 AND t.day = 4 AND t.time < 120000;
```

Apparently, more than one `RFID` can have the same maximum time, so joining only on `time` doesn't work.

EDIT:

You should verify that you actually have data to delete:

```
select ai.rfid, max(ai.time), min(ai.time), count(*)
from attendance_images ai
where ai.year = 2016 AND ai.month = 8 AND ai.day = 4 AND ai.time < 120000
group by ai.rfid
having min(ai.time) < max(ai.time);
```

My guess is that this will return no rows, indicating that you have have no such duplicates.

You can change the `having` clause to `having count(*) > 1` to see if you have duplicates that have the same `time` value.

EDIT II:

The indentation of the values in the query suggest that `time` is stored as a string, not an integer.  You might try replacing the condition:

```
t.time < 120000
```

with:

```
t.time + 0 < 120000
```

Comment: I run the query but still the same issue

Comment: @GM.Akbar . . . That would suggest that you don't have duplicates that meet your condition.  See check I added to the answer.