# Mysql delete similar rows according to specific columns except the ones with highest id

Tags: mysql

my table has duplicate row values in specific columns. i would like to remove those rows and keep the row with the latest id.
the columns i want to check and compare are:

```
sub_id, spec_id, ex_time
```

so, for this table

```
+----+--------+---------+---------+-------+
| id | sub_id | spec_id | ex_time | count |
+----+--------+---------+---------+-------+
|  1 |    100 |     444 | 09:29   |     2 |
|  2 |    101 |     555 | 10:01   |    10 |
|  3 |    100 |     444 | 09:29   |    23 |
|  4 |    200 |     321 | 05:15   |     5 |
|  5 |    100 |     444 | 09:29   |     8 |
|  6 |    101 |     555 | 10:01   |     1 |
+----+--------+---------+---------+-------+
```

i would like to get this result

```
+----+--------+---------+---------+-------+
| id | sub_id | spec_id | ex_time | count |
+----+--------+---------+---------+-------+
|  5 |    100 |     444 | 09:29   |     8 |
|  6 |    101 |     555 | 10:01   |     1 |
+----+--------+---------+---------+-------+
```

i was able to build this query to select all duplicate rows from multiple columns, according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324328/mysql-select-records-for-duplicates-using-multiple-columns)

```
select  t.*
from mytable t join
     (select id, sub_id, spec_id, ex_time, count(*) as NumDuplicates
      from mytable
      group by sub_id, spec_id, ex_time
      having NumDuplicates > 1
     ) tsum
     on t.sub_id = tsum.sub_id and t.spec_id = tsum.spec_id and t.ex_time = tsum.ex_time
```

but now im not sure how to wrap this select with a delete query to delete the rows except for the ones with highest id.
as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38804666/mysql-delete-duplicate-records-except-one-has-max-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can modify your sub-select query, to get maximum value of `id` for each duplication combination.
- Now, while joining to the main table, simply put a condition that `id` value will not be equal to the maximum `id` value.
- You can now `Delete` from this result-set.

Try the following:

```
DELETE t 
FROM mytable AS t 
JOIN 
    (SELECT MAX(id) as max_id, 
            sub_id, 
            spec_id, 
            ex_time, 
            COUNT(*) as NumDuplicates
     FROM mytable
     GROUP BY sub_id, spec_id, ex_time
     HAVING NumDuplicates > 1
    ) AS tsum
     ON t.sub_id = tsum.sub_id AND 
        t.spec_id = tsum.spec_id AND 
        t.ex_time = tsum.ex_time AND 
        t.id <> tsum.max_id
```